# svcutil.exe issue with configuration name

Tags: svcutil.exe

I am updating my wcf service reference through SvcUtil.exe.
command is as follows:

SvcUtil.exe http://localhost:50886/Service1.svc /n:*,ClassLibrary2.ServiceReference1 /o:Service References\ServiceReference1\Reference.cs /ct:System.Collections.Generic.List`1, mscorlib, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089 /config:app.config

And my wcf code is as follows:

==============================================================

```
namespace WcfService1
{
    [ServiceContract]
    [ServiceKnownType(typeof(Dictionary<string, string>))]
    public interface **IService1**
    {
        [OperationContract]
        string GetData(int value);
        // TODO: Add your service operations here
        [OperationContract]
        string Hello(string value);
    }
}



namespace WcfService1
{

    [ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.PerCall)]
    [AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode = AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Allowed)]

    public class Service1 : IService1
    {
        public string GetData(int value)
        {
            return string.Format("You entered: {0}", value);
        }

        public string Hello(string value)
        {
            return string.Format("You entered: {0}", value);
        }
    }
}
```

I am using this service in my class library project which name is ClassLibrary1. When i am updating this service through visual studio then in Reference.cs I got following statement:

```
[System.ServiceModel.ServiceContractAttribute(ConfigurationName="**ServiceReference1.IService1**")]
public interface IService1
```

But when m updating service through svcutil then I got following statement:

```
[System.ServiceModel.ServiceContractAttribute(ConfigurationName="**ClassLibrary2.ServiceReference1.IService1**")]
public interface IService1
```

The difference is configuration name. I didn't understand which command should i used in svcutil to set configuration name just as **ServiceReference1.IService1** ?

Please help.

Answer (score 1):

Just by changing `[ServiceContract]` into `[ServiceContract(Name="ServiceReference1.IService1", ConfigurationName="ServiceReference1.IService1")]`. See [this block post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/drnick/archive/2008/05/09/setting-the-configuration-name.aspx).